# get string to ng-model value angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

I have 10 input fields each of them looks like:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='value1' ng-keyup='checkValue($event)'>
```

now inside my angular controller, the `checkValue` function is

```
$scope.checkValue = function(event){
  if(event.target.value > someOtherDynamicValue){
    // I have to reset the value here
    event.target.value = "";
  }
}
```

here the value is getting empty if the `if` condition is true but the problem is this value is not removing from `ng-model`. So I tried to access the `ng-model` name of the target element like this:

```
var modelName = angular.element(event.target)[0]attributes[2].nodeValue;
```

So now in `modelName` i have the `ng-model` name of the target element and I tried to reset it :

```
$scope.modelName = "";
```

So finally my code looks like:

```
$scope.checkValue = function(event){
      if(event.target.value > someOtherDynamicValue){
        // I have to reset the value here
        event.target.value = "";
        var modelName = angular.element(event.target)[0]attributes[2].nodeValue;
        $scope.modelName = "";
      }
    }
```

I know it is treating `$scope.modelName` as a new independent scope variable but how can I change the value of `ng-model`?

**EDIT**

What I really want to achieve is: I have 10 fields with different `ng-model` name now when I am writing the angular function, I don't want to use the `ng-model` directly inside the function. Example:

```
$scope.checkValue = function(event){
  if(event.target.value > someOtherDynamicValue){
    // I have to reset the value here
    $scope.value1 = ""; //I don't want to do this, because $scope.value1 is for one text field and I have 10 filed if i use this i need to write it 10 times 
  }
}
```

So `$scope.value1` I want to generate dynamically using `event.target`.

Thanks.

Comment: Pass your value1 variable in the checkValue function itself. So your function will have definition like this - `function(event, value)`

Comment: Then change value in your function - `value = event.target.value`

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.value1 = ''` after `event.target.value = "";` should work. I think you no need also this: `event.target.value = "";`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ep9CxaIf31auDDlYo82I?p=preview here it is working

Comment: @Jagadesha_NH In this https://plnkr.co/edit/Ep9CxaIf31auDDlYo82I?p=preview example if u check like `<p>{{home.val1}}</p>` then you will understand what actually my problem is.

Comment: I tried reading the comments and the code you've posted, and it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.   This *feels like* an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619), you are describing a problem with your calculations being wrong after trying your one possible solution using `$event` here, but it's not really clear what the calculation you are trying to perform means, or what results you expect from it, especially when you start talking about the fields being "dynamic"...

Comment: You didn't explain your problem well. That's why no one has answered this simple question. My advice to you: edit question to make it clear what is the goal and problem you face.

Comment: your code sample has 3 separate input boxes, and you seem to be checking all 3 boxes for the same condition, and changing the value of both the first and the second based on whatever is entered;  why would entering a value in box 2 affect box 1, or box 3 affect either, and what would a calculation with 20 boxes (from your comment to an answer) even look like?  and why would you be writing 0 in the same box I tried to type a different number into?

Comment: so based on your edit, I ask again, why don't you pass the ng-model value to the function, rather than `$event`?  `ng-model='value1' ng-keyup='checkValue(value1)'` ?

Comment: @claies, Thanks now i got the point.

Answer (score 0):

Based on values you enter on third textbox values of one and two changes

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('TestApp', []).controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function HomeController($scope) {

  var home = this;

  home.checkValue = function($event) {
    if ($event.target.value < 100) {
      home.val1 = 0;
    }else{
      home.val2 = 10;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HomeController as home">
      <div>
      {{ home.val1 }} | {{ home.val2 }} | {{ home.val3}}
      </div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="home.val1" ng-keyup='home.checkValue($event)'>
    <input type="number" ng-model="home.val2" ng-keyup='home.checkValue($event)'>
    <input type="number" ng-model="home.val3" ng-keyup='home.checkValue($event)'>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Jagadesha_NH `home.val1`, `home.val2` are the dynamic values I can't use the name directly in the `checkValue ` function. Assume if I have 20 input fields then I need to write 20 variable names in the function.

Comment: did u check ng-init?

Comment: ng-model="post.user_id" ng-init="post.user_id=dynamic-value"